# Getting the last line printed in Ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax, global-variables

Is there any way to get the output of the last string sent to output? For instance:

```
 puts "Hello"
 puts _+" World"
```

*Would return*

```
 Hello
 Hello World
```

The assignment I'm working on involves minimizing code as much as possible. The above example is not the assignment, but if such a variable exists it would certainly help.

Thanks

** **EDIT** **

@gnibbler has the closest answer to what I'm looking for. This has nothing to do with spacing. I need to reuse the data output on the previous line, not append to it. Another example would be:

```
 puts "foobar"   // foobar
 puts _.reverse  // raboof
```

Comment: This question actually has nothing to do with the line change, I need to reuse the data on the previous line, not append to it.

Comment: Why can't you just keep that in your own variable, then?

Comment: I can, but this is a code minification assignment. I'm trying to find ways to shorten my code to the absolute minimum required to produce the desired output.

Comment: When you are finished, consider posting your problem here http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles?referrer=TjrEmgZecu1qY44vShJFww2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah its possible. You need to override the Kernel::puts method likes this

```
module Kernel
   alias_method :old_puts, :puts
   def puts arg
       old_puts arg
       $_=arg  # $_ is a global variable, holds the last printed item
   end
end
```

and use it like

```
>> puts "sample"
=> "sample"
>> _
=> "sample"
>> _.reverse
=> "elpmas"
```

_ will always holds the last printed value

it means

```
>> puts "hello" 
=> "hello"
>> puts _ + " word"
=> "hello word"
>> _
=> "hello word"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no special variable for that

apart from patching puts (which will conflict with your requirement to minimise the code), you could use a pattern like this

```
puts w="Hello"
puts w=(w+" World")
puts w=(w.reverse)
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason that you want to do this?maybe there is other solutions. If you really wants to do, you can do like this:

```
module Kernel
  alias_method :puts_with_save, :puts
  def puts_with_save arg_
    puts arg_
    $LastPuts = arg_
  end
end

puts_with_save "hello" 
puts_with_save $LastPuts + " shanison"
```

This should work as you expected. But I introduce a global $LastPuts to your program.

Comment: There are, but I'm still trying to find the best solution myself before I cave and ask for help. That's why I'm only asking for referential information and not simply posting the problem. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that if you knew you were using `puts` you could patch it with your own version to give it a "memory" to suit your objective.  However, it sounds like in your case you may as well use a separate mechanism rather than overriding the default behavior of `puts`.